# Error with Mergesort implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I am learning to implement a mergesort algorithm for use to count inversions. Here is my current implementation of mergesort. However it is not working as it does not return a sorted array. Will anyone be able to tell me what is being done wrongly in this code which I have written? It should sort the array v which is input into the function.

```
void mergeCountInversion(vector<int> v, int l, int r)
{
    if (l >= r)
    {
        return;
    }

    int m = (l + r)/2;  

    //call merge sort to return two sorted arrays
    mergeCountInversion(v, l, m);
    mergeCountInversion(v, m+1, r);

    int left = l;
    int right = m+1;
    std::vector<int> vtemp ;

    //merge and sort the two sorted array, storing the sorted array in vtemp
    for (int k = l; k <= r; ++k){
        if (left >= m+1)
        {
            vtemp.push_back(v[right]);
            right++;
        }
        else if (right > r)
        {
            vtemp.push_back(v[left]);
            left++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (v[left] <= v[right])
            {
                vtemp.push_back(v[left]);
                left++;
            }
            else{
                vtemp.push_back(v[right]);
                right++;
                count += m + 1 - left;
            }
        }
    }

    //replace v with the sorted array vtemp
    for (int i = 0; i < vtemp.size(); ++i)
    {
        v[l+i] = vtemp[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The function does not return anything, so your question is unclear. Please take a few minutes to study the posting guidelines, they explain how to avoid asking non-helpful questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

You are passing the vector by value, but you should pass it by refernce.

If you declare the function as `void` You can't `return 0;`, just `return;`.

When you create `vtemp` you should know exactly its size: r - l. So you can reserve memory for it and you don't need to push_back.

You have to pass count to the function too.

Your function can be:

```
void mergeCountInversion(vector<int> & v, int l, int r, int & count) {
    if (l >= r) return;

    int m = (l + r)/2;  

    //call merge sort to return two sorted arrays
    mergeCountInversion(v, l, m, count);
    mergeCountInversion(v, m+1, r, count);

    int left = l;
    int right = m+1;
    std::vector<int> vtemp(r-l);

    //merge and sort the two sorted array, storing the sorted array in vtemp
    for (int k = l; k <= r; ++k) {
        if (left >= m+1) {
            vtemp[k] = v[right];
            right++;
        }
        else if (right > r) {
            vtemp[k] =  v[left];
            left++;
        }
        else {
            if (v[left] <= v[right]) {
                vtemp[k] = v[left];
                left++;
            }
            else {
                vtemp[k] = v[right];
                right++;
                count += m + 1 - left;
            }
       }
    }

    //replace v with the sorted array vtemp
    for (int i = 0; i < vtemp.size(); ++i)
    v[l+i] = vtemp[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined

```
void mergeCountInversion(vector<int> v, int l, int r)
```

then you first call `mergeCountInversion` recursively, and modify `v` after the calls returned.

The problem is that the changes to `v` made in the recursive calls will never be seen, because `v` is **passed by value**.

Try to pass `v` **by reference**:

```
void mergeCountInversion(vector<int>& v, int l, int r)
```

such that all calls work on the same copy of `v`.